# How can I print a field value in node.html.twig?

Tags: 8, entities

I want to print a field value in node.html.twig. When I use `{{ content.field_test }}`, it prints the full HTML markup of the field.

How can I just print the field value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you can print the first value of the field without the surrounding div container with `{{ content.field_test[0] }}`, this is not a recommend way to do it.

The markup you want to change is in the field template. If you don't want for example any div's around the field `field-test`, then place a field template in the template folder of the theme:

*field--field-test.html.twig*:

```
<span{{ attributes }}>
  {%- for item in items -%}
    {{ item.content }}
  {%- endfor -%}
</span>
```

The benefit you get is that this outputs multi-value fields and that you keep the attributes of the field, which is important if you want the theme to work with core and third-party modules for client side functionality like, for example, quickedit.

Comment: I want use command directly .

Answer (score 6):

This will help:

[Twig Field Value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) :  It gives them more control over the output without drilling deep into the render array or using preprocess functions.